# How to do a custom interactive "map" with an image with React?

Tags: reactjs, image, dictionary, tooltip

I'm trying to set up an interactive "map" using react but I don't see how to set it up.

my interactive map is an aerial image of a place on which I would like to add hotspots that display a preview of the place with another image.

Afterwards if I click on a preview I would like to display the image in real size but I don't see how to do it...

I use React

I am open to any advice and any proposal!

thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Look into Leaflet https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html, it has npm packages that integrate it with react https://react-leaflet.js.org/.

Leaflet allows you to display a map and create custom HTML based Marker components. These markers can listen to user interaction events such as onClick and onMouseOver. On catching a user click or hover event, you can render whatever you need on top of the marker - such as your image, maybe with a nice title, description or whatever else you might need.

On clicking the image, you might want to display the image with different CSS styles in another view, so that you can display it in full width and height, or you might even setup a link to the original image URL, which would be much simpler, but at the same time it would drive users temporarily out of your site.

```
import React from 'react'
import { divIcon } from 'leaflet'
import { Marker } from 'react-leaflet'
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server'
import PropTypes from 'proptypes'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

const Index = props => {
    const iconMarkup = renderToStaticMarkup(
        <i
            className="dispatcher-marker fa fa-map-marker-alt"
            style={{ color: props.location.color }}
        />
    )

    const customMarkerIcon = divIcon({
        html: iconMarkup
    })

    return (
        <Marker
            position={[ props.location.lat, props.location.lng ]}
            icon={customMarkerIcon}
            opacity={props.opacity}
            onClick={() => props.handleClick(props.location.id, props.route)}
        />
    )
}

Index.propTypes = {
    handleClick: PropTypes.func,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    route: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    opacity: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
}

export default Index
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know it was possible to use an image with leaflet, i use it with OpenStreetMap

Comment: It's a little more difficult to setup, but you can use entire HTML markup to change what you display instead of your markers, I will post a code example for you to the answer above - in the example, I am using i elements to display icons, since my use case required me to use differently colored, font-awesome based icons